# trying to insert the td values into progress bar using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to insert the value of classes pl1 and pl2 300 and -600 over green bar and red bar.
Value has to be linked directly to td classes pl1 and pl2 using jquery / javascript
by adding the codes to current jquery. Also html tags are restricted to be modified because it is just a part of long project and hence cannot be modified unless very important.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         .pct > div >.bar2 {
         margin-right: 2px;
         text-align: right;
         background: red;
         border: 1px;
         }
         .pct{
         width:auto;
         border: solid purple 1px;
         }
         table, td {
         border: solid black 1px;
         }
         .pl1,.pl2 {
         width: auto;
         display: none;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="kk">OI%</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="nm">Nitin</td>
            <td class="pl1">300</td>
            <td class="pct">
               <div class="progressbar">
                  <div class="bar"></div>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td class="pl2">-600</td>
            <td class="pct">
               <div class="progressbar">
                  <div class="bar"></div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <script>
         $( function() {
               let sal = $(".pl1 ,.pl2 ");
               
               let progressbarSize = 100; //100%
               
               
               $(".progressbar").css("width", "auto" + "px")
                             
               $(".bar").css({width : ("auto") + "px", height : "20px", display : "inline"});
               
               $(".bar").css("float", "left" )
              
               
               
                     
               $(sal).each(function(index, element){
                 let currentValue = parseInt($(element).text());
                 
                 //console.log(currentValue);
                 
                 if (currentValue >= 0 && currentValue <= progressbarSize){
                  
         
                   //console.log(currentValue);
                   $(element).next().children().children(".bar").css("backgroundColor", "#00ff00")
                   .css("width", (currentValue) + "px")
                    
                   
         
                 }
                 else if (currentValue >= 0 && currentValue >= progressbarSize){
         
                   //console.log(currentValue);
                   progressbarSize = currentValue;
                   
                   $(element).next().children().children(".bar").css("backgroundColor", "#00ff00")
                   .css("width", (currentValue) + "px")
                   
         
                 }
                 
                 else if(currentValue >= (progressbarSize * -1) && currentValue < 0){
                 
          
                   //console.log(currentValue);
                   currentValue *= -1;
                   
                  
                   $(element).next().children().children(".bar").css("backgroundColor", "red")
                   .css("width", (currentValue) + "px")
                   
                   
                 }
                 
                 else if(currentValue <= (progressbarSize * -1) && currentValue < 0){
                   
                   //console.log(currentValue);
                   
                   currentValue *= -1;
                   
                   $(element).next().children().children(".bar").css("backgroundColor", "red")
                   .css("width", (currentValue) + "px")
                   
                   
                 }
                 
                 else{
                   
                   $(element).next().children().children().hide(); //Hide the both, possitive and negative.
                   
                 }
                 
               });
               });
              
               
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".kk").after('<th class="kkv2"></th>');
jQuery(".kk").text(jQuery(".pl1").text());
jQuery(".kkv2").text(jQuery(".pl2").text());
```

Comment: not working its adding the values on the header.
whereas the values are to be added on same div under the green bar.
Technically the values to be inserted into div class .bar

Comment: thanks, I managed to make it work by modifying your lines.
It worked.

Comment: Glad it helped.